# Xamarin Forms: Close App from Login Screen using NavigationStack

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigation

I am stuck at a place for sometime now and cannot find any help on it.

**Scenario:**
I have a Xamarin Forms app. When the app starts, I check if the user is logged in or not. If the user is logged in, I open Main Screen. But if the user is not logged in, I open the login view as `Modal` page `Navigation.PushModalAsync` on top of main screen.
Once the user is logged in, I remove this page and show my original Main page.

**Problem**
When the user presses `Back` button on phone, I want the Application to Exit. How can I do that.

Note: I am using Navigation stack to push and pop pages. In this case, I guess, I have to pop all the pages. But I can't figure out how.

Comment: Do you mean the Hardware Back button? If so, the issue is only for android, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the back button is only an issue on Android devices, you can override `OnBackButtonPressed()` to call a dependency service to close the app.  In your `LoginPage` add this:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    DependencyService.Get<IAndroidMethods>().CloseApp();
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

I made my dependency service off of my IAndroidMethods interface which I implemented in my MyApp.Droid project:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AndroidMethods))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class AndroidMethods : IAndroidMethods
    {
        public void CloseApp()
        {
            //This closes the Android app
            Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
        }
    }
}
```

Now when the back button is pressed from your login page, the app will close.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `MainActivity.cs` add this:

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    if (App.ImInLoginView)
    {
        Finish();
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Where `App.ImInLoginView` Is a flag I use as a reference (inside my App.cs):

`public static bool ImInLoginView;`

Which I turn it on/off in the OnAppearing and OnDisappearing events.

I hope this helps.

Comment: where is the `Finish();` function defined? what does it do?

Comment: Finish() Terminates the application and it is a Method of the Activities.

Comment: Thanks. but cvanbeek's solution is working fine. I'll stick with that for now.